# Security proof of partially blind signature (schnorr signature based)

Tags: schnorr-signature, schnorr-identification

I read [a representative paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-44598-6_17) about partially blind signature.

Abe and Okamoto - "provably secure partially blind signature".

They suggested a partially blind signature scheme based on Schnorr signature.

In the security proof section, they proved that the scheme is secure against adaptive chosen message attack using ID reduction scheme.

---

They assume a single-info adversary, $U^{*}$ that violates unforgeability for infinitely many sizes.

And the machine ${M}$ is constructed by a forger ${U^*}$.

Firstly, ${M}$ select $b$ (0 or 1, randomly) and assigns $(y, z)=(g^{x}, z_{0}g^{\gamma})$ if $b=0$, or $(y, z)=(z_{0}g^{\gamma}, g^{w})$ if $b=1$.

$\gamma, x$ (or $w$) is chosend randomly.

Random oracle $F$ is defined so that it returns appropriate value of $z$ according to above selection.

Let's assume that $b=0$.

If $U^{*}$ is successful with probability at least $\eta$, then the author says we can find a random tape string for $U^{*}$ with probability at least 1/2 such that $U^{*}$ succeeds with probability $\eta/2$.

I cannot understand what 'finding a random tape' means.

Does it mean finding $\gamma$ and $x$?

Why is it 1/2 and $\eta/2$ ?

Below is a capture of the paper.

[image]

[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows by the probing strategy/heavy-row lemma, which traces back to [Oka,FFS]. Read §6 in [this](http://theory.stanford.edu/~dfreeman/papers/HPL-2005-154.pdf) paper for a nicer explanation.

References:
[Oka]: Okamoto. Provably Secure and Practical Identification Schemes and Corresponding Signature Schemes. CRYPTO 1992.
[FFS]: Feige, Fiat and Shamir. Zero-knowledge proofs of identity. JoC 1988.

Comment: Another good resource on the heavy row lemma is Hazay/Lindell's textbook: "Efficient secure two party protocols," Chapter 6.3 - "Proofs of Knowledge"